# How to exclude main domain from subdomain tracking in Google Analytics or GTM?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have subdomains, lets say **site1.example.com, site2.example.com, site3.example.com** and the main site example.com. My goal is to work with all traffic from site1,site2,site3 on site1.example.com except of example.com and www.example.com.

Each website has personal GTM container and tracking object.
How can I set subdomain tracking via GTM and **exclude example.com from tracking**. I've already read simoahava and lunametric posts regarding the issue but didn't find suitable answer.

Comment: You have several options:   1.  Remove the tracking snippet from the domains you don't want tracked.   2.  Implement a filter in GA  3.  Create an advanced segment to view reports for just the subdomain.      The first two wouldn't allow the main domain to be tracked at all, the last one would let you turn it on and off.  Which fits in this case?